# the product of distinct roots of polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, integers

Suppose $n ≥ 2$ , and
$f(x)=a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+⋯+a_1 x+a_0∈\mathbb Z[X]$ with $a_n≠0$.

$M_{1}, M_{2},...,M_{r}$ are the distinct roots of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb C$.

> Show that $a_{n}M_{1}M_{2}...M_{r}∈\mathbb Z$.

I know that $a_{n}M_{1}$ is an algebraic integer.

NOTE that the roots we have just the distinct ones and so we can not use the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: What tools are you aware of that might help in solving this problem?  Are there any attempts you have made so far?

Comment: Hint: you can find an *exact* formula for $a_nM_1M_2\cdots M_r$ in terms of the other coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: The product is an algebraic integer, if we prove that the product is also rational number we'll get the result

Comment: @ks1: You are overthinking this. This is an elementary problem. There is no need to use anything beyond high school algebra.

Comment: note that we have r roots not n

Comment: Hint: the [radical](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228939/242) $\,{r}(f) := f/\gcd(f,f')\in \Bbb Q[x]\,$ has no repeated roots, and can be scaled by a rational to be a factor of $f$ in $\Bbb Z[x]\,$ by Gauss's Lemma.